# How do I handle a null Guid in a generic function?

Tags: c#

Consider

```
    public static T Get<T>(this ICache cache, string key)
    {
        var obj = cache.Get(key);
        return (T)obj;
    }
```

if T happens to be Guid, and obj is null (does not exist in cache), an exception occurs because Guid cannot be null. Is it possible to make Get working? I tried adding a `typeof(T) == typeof(Guid)` check, but it is not possible to cast Guid into T. Puzzler!

**Update** @mihai, as doesn't work for me

[image]

**Update2** Since Guid is not nullable, then I presume I would look for default(Guid) which is Guid.Empty. Should have put it in the original request. Thank you for everyone's contribution.

Comment: What would you *want* to be returned in that case?  If not an exception, then it would have to be some specific value.  Perhaps the default value?  It's up to you.  The compiler won't decide for you.

Comment: default value (Guid.Empty)

Comment: You could use reflection, to validate the underlying type.  But that would be a whole different can of worms.

Comment: Note that this can be quite dangerous.  For example, suppose you have `x --> 1` in your cache and you call `cache.Get<double>("x")` -- what happens?  You can cast an *unboxed* into to double, but you cannot cast a boxed int to double, and you have a boxed int here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if (obj == null)
   return default(T);
else
   return (T)obj;
```

Comment: default(T) is a good move - but will it give me null when I want it to? say a string type that is not in a cache, I should get null, not string.Empty

Comment: @tofutim it returns whatever the default is

Comment: I'm tempted to ` if (obj == null && typeof(T) == typeof(Guid)) return default(T);`

Comment: @tofutim You don't need to do that unless you want the cast to fail in the same way for other value types.

Comment: null is a good indicator to me that there is no cache hit, but default(string) could cause an issue

Comment: is there a test for nullable?

Comment: `default(string)` returns `null` in my test.

Comment: @tofutim `default(string)` is `null` which is the same result as casting.

Comment: is the default value for all nullable types and all classes null?

Comment: @tofutim Yes, all reference types (classes) default to `null`.  And `Nullable<T>` defaults to a value that is equivalent to `null`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337551/why-is-the-default-value-of-the-string-type-null-instead-of-an-empty-string

Answer (score 3):

Your problem can be solved simply checking the `null` case:

```
public static T Get<T>(this ICache cache, string key)
{
    var obj = cache.Get(key);
    return obj == null ? default(T) : (T)obj;
}
```

But now you have a different problem; if `T` is a struct, you won't know if a returned default value is due to the cache returning null or because the cached value is in fact the default one (if `Guid` is the only value type you are expecting then this wouldn't be much of an issue because a default `Guid` isn't really a valid `Guid` to begin with).

Solution? Return the necessary info to discern both scenarios:

```
public static bool TryGet<T>(this ICache cache, string key, out T result)
{
    var obj = cache.Get(key);

    if (obj == null)
    {
        result = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    result = (T)obj;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you want to be able to get back a nullable GUID, then *just ask for a nullable GUID*, rather than writing a super annoying method that tries to provide multiple separate values, which of course the language wasn't designed to support conveniently, or by returning an incorrect value some of the time.

Comment: @Servy I'm over here just shaking my head

Comment: I don't want a nullable Guid.

Comment: @Servy I agree, but the answer doesn't state that it only has to work the a nullable `Guid`, the question clearly states "if `T` *happens* to be a `Guid`..." That seems to imply `T` can be many other things. I tend to answer what is being asked and not make assumptions that can be wrong, questions tend to simplify much more involved scenarios.

Comment: @InBetween Sure, the question doesn't state what they want to happen at all.  If you just want to provide what they've asked for then *there is nothing to provide*.

Comment: @tofutim So then what do you want?  What is the caller of this method expecting to happen when they ask for a `Guid` that doesn't exist?  (Note you should edit your question to explain what you actually want, rather than just telling me.)

Comment: Guid.Empty (the default value), but null for all nullable types; btw, I acknowledge that this is a 'why are you asking this question' -

Comment: @tofutim Then why isn't that in the question?  And what should every other non-nullable type do when it has a null value?

Comment: What do you think about following solution ? http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2012/03/06/Convert-to-unknown-generic-type-ChangeType-T.aspx